# What is the exact query for below

Tags: mysql, sql

I am beginner in SQL
This is my patient table

| id | patientName | gender | familyType | mobileAppId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz | m | p | 1 |
| 2 | abc | m | c | 1 |
| 3 | pqr | f | c | 2 |
| 4 | ghi | f | p | 3 |
| 5 | lmn | f | c | 3 |
| 6 | ppp | f | c | 3 |
| 7 | kkk | f | c | 1 |

if i search id = 1 then , i need to get id 1 and 2 row because id 1's family type is 'p' so it return mobile app id is same rows

if i search id = 2 i need to get only id 2nd row(bcz it's family type = c)

if i search id = 3 i need to get only id 3rd row(bcz it's family type = c)

if i search id = 4 i need to get 4th,5th,6th row(bcz search id family type = p and mobile app id is same)

note : mobileAppId have only one 'p' familyType and may be more than 1 'c' familyType

I tried many conditions but i did't get expected result

any one please help me?

Comment: What assumptions can we make? Can you have more than one record with family type p and the same mobileappid? Same thing for family type c. Failing that, anyone providing you with an answer will be guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query work:

```sql
select * 
from patient
where 
  (id = <searchId> and familyType = 'c')
  or mobileAppId = (
    select mobileAppId from patient
    where familyType = 'p' and id = <searchId>
  )
```

Online demos:

- [Search for id = 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bc02c/3)
- [Search for id = 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bc02c/4)
- [Search for id = 3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bc02c/5)
- [Search for id = 4](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bc02c/6)
- [Search for id = 7](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bc02c/9)

Note: for `searchId = 1` the row with `id = 7` is also returned because `mobileAppId = 1`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a `LEFT JOIN` on the `mobileAppId` column when `familyType` is `'p'`.

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN c.id IS NULL THEN p.id          ELSE c.id          END AS id         
     , CASE WHEN c.id IS NULL THEN p.patientName ELSE c.patientName END AS patientName
     , CASE WHEN c.id IS NULL THEN p.gender      ELSE c.gender      END AS gender     
     , CASE WHEN c.id IS NULL THEN p.familyType  ELSE c.familyType  END AS familyType 
     , CASE WHEN c.id IS NULL THEN p.mobileAppId ELSE c.mobileAppId END AS mobileAppId
  FROM patient p
  LEFT JOIN patient c ON c.mobileAppId = p.mobileAppId
                     AND p.familyType = 'p'
 WHERE p.id = 1
 ORDER BY id
```

*Result with `id = 1`*

| id | patientName | gender | familyType | mobileAppId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz | m | p | 1 |
| 2 | abc | m | c | 1 |
| 7 | kkk | f | c | 1 |

*Result with `id = 2`*

| id | patientName | gender | familyType | mobileAppId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | abc | m | c | 1 |

*Result with `id = 3`*

| id | patientName | gender | familyType | mobileAppId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | pqr | f | c | 2 |

*Result with `id = 4`*

| id | patientName | gender | familyType | mobileAppId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | ghi | f | p | 3 |
| 5 | lmn | f | c | 3 |
| 6 | ppp | f | c | 3 |

See [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6B7v74qxFoxYA539nsWzSs/0) for results shown above.

Comment: Possibly, `COALESCE(c.id, p.id) AS id, COALESCE(c.patientName, p.patientName) AS patientName`, etc. should be used to make it less verbose

Comment: @AlexRudenko I thought of doing it that way, but if some of the values of a `'c'` record may be `NULL`, that would fail. Assuming `id` is a `NOT NULL` column (fairly safe bet), using `CASE WHEN c.id IS NULL` for all columns is failure-proof. Could alternately use `mobileAppId IS NOT NULL` too, since it is definitely `NOT NULL` for a joined `c` record given the `JOIN` criteria.

Comment: If `JOIN` condition (particularly the part `familyType = 'p'`) is not met, then all fields in `c` are `NULL` [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bc02c/15), so `COALESCE` seems to be quite safe too,

Comment: @AlexRudenko But if e.g. `gender` could be `NULL`, then `COALESCE(c.gender, p.gender)` would pick up the `p` value, even if a `c` record is present, thereby giving incorrect result.